# Применить Material Design к предыдущим версиям

Tags: java, android, android-material

Можно ли применить Material Design к предыдущим версиям api?

Например, заменить диалог старой версии на новый (Material Design) на смартфоне версии 4 и ниже.

**Старая версия**

[image: Старая версия]

**Новая версия**

[image: Новая версия]

Comment: а AppCompat чем не угодил?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь вот этой библиотекой: [Material Dialogs](https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs)

На всех версиях одинаково выглядят диалоги и делать их с ней гораздо приятнее и проще.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: спосиба %^&%^%^)))